# Rails index uniqueness with specific value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, indexing, unique

I'd like to create a unique index for a table, consisting of 3 columns, but 
to check only if one of them has a specific value:

something like
add_index :table, [:col1, :col2, :col3], unique: true

but only if col3 = true,
otherwise I don't care about col1, col2, :col3 = false uniqueness.

is there a way to do it in a migration to keep it at the DB level, or can I only
validate this case in the model?

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe you can have conditional uniqueness constraints at the database layer (via migrations).  You can add this as a [conditional validation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#conditional-validation) at the AR layer though which should be sufficient for your purposes (though it should be noted this can introduce some race conditions). ie.

> validates [:col1, :col2], uniqueness: true, if: ":col3 == true"

Hope that helps.